# Как поместить в пременную значение дата время?

Tags: linux, c, дата, время

Получаю дату время

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
struct timespec ts;

timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);

char buff[100];

strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(&ts.tv_sec));

printf("[%s.%09ld]\n", buff, ts.tv_nsec);

return 0;
}
```

но не могу сообразить как поместить в переменную полученный результат что бы не дописывать в

> printf("[%s.%09ld]\n", buff, ts.tv_nsec);

а использовать для конечного результата одну переменную пример: printf(end_result)?

Comment: `sprintf` к концу строки не устраивает?

Comment: Так работает, поставьте в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, раз автора вопроса устраивает...

```
char buff[100];
strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(&ts.tv_sec));
sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),".%09ld]\n", buff, ts.tv_nsec);
```

Можно (нужно!) использовать более безопасные версии типа `snprintf` или `sprintf_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать печать совсем без промежуточного буфера:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec ts;

    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    const struct tm *t = gmtime(&ts.tv_sec);

    printf(
        "[%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%09ld]\n",
        t->tm_year + 1900,
        t->tm_mon + 1,
        t->tm_mday,
        t->tm_hour,
        t->tm_min,
        t->tm_sec,
        ts.tv_nsec
    );
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc timestamp.c
>
> $ ./a.out
> [2024-03-25 17:42:22.535546099]
>
> $ ./a.out
> [2024-03-25 17:42:23.895268541]
> ```